# memory leak in c++ and how to fix it

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I am getting this error with memory leak,
I know i have to deallocate the memory but how to do it
I am getting this error with memory leak,
I know i have to deallocate the memory but how to do it please guide

```
SongCollection::SongCollection(char* filename) {
 try {
  std::ifstream file("songs.txt");
  if (file) {
   while (file) {
    std::string temp, t_artist, t_title, t_album, t_price, t_year, t_length;
    std::getline(file, temp, '\n'); 
    if (!(temp.length() < 25)) {
     t_title = temp.substr(0, 25); 
     t_artist = temp.substr(25, 25); 
     t_album = temp.substr(50, 25); 
     t_year = temp.substr(75, 5); 
     t_length = temp.substr(80, 5); 
     t_price = temp.substr(85, 5);
     auto strip = [&](std::string& str) { 
      str = str.substr(str.find_first_not_of(" "), str.find_last_not_of(" ") + 1); 
      str = str.substr(0, str.find_last_not_of(" ") + 1); 
     };
     strip(t_title); 
     strip(t_artist); 
     strip(t_album);
     m_storage = new Song;
     m_storage->m_title = t_title;
     m_storage->m_artist = t_artist;
     m_storage->m_album = t_album;
     try {
      m_storage->m_year = std::stoi(t_year);
     }
     catch (...) {
      m_storage->m_year = 0;
     }
     m_storage->m_length = std::stoi(t_length);
     m_storage->m_price = std::stod(t_price);
     collection.push_back(m_storage);
    }
   }
  }
  else {
   throw 1;
  }
 }
 catch (int& err) {
  std::cerr << "ERROR: Cannot open file [" << filename << "].\n";
  exit(err);
 }
}

SongCollection::~SongCollection() {
 if (m_storage) {
  delete m_storage;
  m_storage = nullptr;
 }
 collection.clear();
}
```

And I got this memory leak report

```
==141379== 2,345 (2,128 direct, 217 indirect) bytes in 19 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 3 
==141379==    at 0x4C2A593: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:344) 
==141379==    by 0x403991: sdds::SongCollection::SongCollection(char*) (SongCollection.cpp:34) 
==141379==    by 0x402856: main (w7_p2_prof.cpp:29)
```

Comment: Best way of dealing with all memory leaks in C++ is to use classes from the header `<memory>` instead of managing it manually. https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/

Comment: First of all, `m_storage` should not be member variable. It should be a *local* variable. Then you have a container of pointers (`collection`) and you never delete those objects. And lastly, there's no need for pointers at all here, use a container of `Song` ***objects*** instead.

Comment: On a couple of unrelated notes, why do you pass a `filename` to the `SongCollection` constructor, and not use it? And why isn't the string a `std::string`? And please add some empty lines in your code to split it into paragraphs. That will make it much easier to read.

Comment: Can you please show me how to fix it

Comment: You do `while (file)` multiple times and each time you create a new song (`m_storage = new Song;`) but you remove only one song in the destructor. All the remaining pointers are overridden and lost because you save all of them to the same field. You probably want some list of pointers instead. Although, I have similar doubts to Someprogrammerdude. I don't know why do you even need dynamic memory allocation here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "best"™ solution is to not use pointers at all, as then there's no dynamic allocation that you can forget to delete.

For your case it includes a few rather minor changes to make it work.

First of all I recommend you create a `Song` constructor taking all needed values as arguments, then it becomes easier to create `Song` objects:

```
Song::Song(std::string const& title, std::string const& artist, std::string const& album, unsigned year)
    : m_title(title), m_artist(artist), m_album(album), m_year(year)
{
}
```

Then inside your `SongCollection` class use a vector of `Song` *objects* instead of pointers:

```
std::vector<Song> collection;
```

Then add songs to the vector while creating the objects all in one go:

```
 try {
  t_year = std::stoi(t_year);
 }
 catch (...) {
  t_year = 0;
 }

 collection.emplace_back(t_title, t_artist, t_album, t_year);
```

And finally remove the `SongCollection` destructor.

No pointers, no (explicit) dynamic allocation, no memory leaks. And no breaking [the rules of three/five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), by following the rule of zero.